# Foundation for Apps, how to change view on form submit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router, zurb-foundation

Excited to find out about Foundation for Apps coming bundled with AngularJS, I took this as an excuse to start learning AngularJS. I try to recreate parts of an old web app to see what's possible with this new framework. And I hit a roadblock:

One of the views is a search form. On "submit" it should slide away and the "Result" view should slide in. Now, switching those views using `<a ui-sref="">` (like in a navigation menu) works fine. 
But how to trigger this - and have the SearchField InputValue passed on as parameter - on formSubmit?

Following the example given in http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/angular I created a controller that is attached to the form like this.

`<form ng-controller="StaffSearchController" ng-submit="doSearch()" >`

```
angular.module('application').controller('StaffSearchController', StaffSearchController);
StaffSearchController.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$controller'];
function StaffSearchController($scope, $stateParams, $state, $controller) {
    angular.extend(this, $controller('DefaultController', {$scope: $scope, $stateParams: $stateParams, $state: $state }));
    console.info("StaffSearchController");
    $scope.searchTerm = "search me";
    $scope.doSearch = function(){
      console.log("doSearch");
    };
}
```

The `doSearch()` gets called. but what do do from there to switch to the next view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `$state.go('stateName');` which will find correct state from $stateProvider and redirect you on that page with specific controller template and all specified setting inside its `.state`

For state with parameters you could use `$state.go('stateName', {id: 1});`

> Note: Before doing `$state.go` don't forget to add `$state` dependency
>   on controller

For more info refer [**Doc**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)